# how to access unity container at application_beginrequest using asp.net mvc and unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, unity-container

using asp.net mvc and installing [unity bootstraper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/3.5.1404) through nuget.

I was wondering how can I get access to same unity container at **"Application_BeginRequest()"**,**"Application_Error()"**,**"Application_EndRequest()"** that is configured in bootstraper ?

and how can I resolve all instances of an interface at Application_BeginRequest?

Comment: Why do you want to get Unity container in Application_BeginRequest(). You can simply cal Initialize method of bootstraper in the Application_Start right? Is there any specific reason for doing in Application_BeginRequest()? Also resolving dependencies per Request is a bad idea. Instead you need to do that in Application_Start event only.

Comment: i want to be able to handle transaction per request pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325902/how-to-register-all-types-of-an-interface-and-get-instance-of-them-in-unity

Answer (score 8):

In MVC, your dependency container is available as a singleton at `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current`

Comment: How do i resolve all instances of an interface using System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current ?

Comment: `DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IMyService>()`