# Registering all classes in Microsoft Unity DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am working on a project based on `Asp.Net WebForms`, i am using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity` for my `DI` purposes, and it seems to be working fine.

Currently i have to load each individual classes in Unity and it's fine, since my project is not that large, but i was wondering is it possible to add all the classes at once in Unity, i have seen the same in `Castle.Windsor` where i can load all the classes at once. Here's what i am currently doing:

```
var container = this.AddUnity();
conntainer.RegisterType<IArticleDao, ArticleDao>();
```

Could anyone please suggest how could i load all the classes at once.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325902/how-to-register-all-types-of-an-interface-and-get-instance-of-them-in-unity

Comment: I don't see `container.RegisterTypes` function, i just have `container.RegisterType`